# Vertical placement of fullpage float with twocolumn + title + incgraph

Tags: floats, two-column

This MWE gives a page 2 where the figure is placed too far down on the page.
The problem disappears if I comment out `\maketitle` or remove the`twocolumn` option.

Why is this? Is it a bug? How can it be circumvented?

The problem is there also with document class scrartcl.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{incgraph}
\igrset{paper=current, pagestyle=plain}

\begin{document}
\title{title}
\author{author}
\maketitle

Some text.

\begin{figure*}
\begin{inctext}
  \rule{1px}{0.9\textheight}
\end{inctext}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

(The strange behaviour with a fullpage figure* with inctext being too far down on the page does not only appear after `\maketitle`, but in other cases I have got that it has been hard to make a small example which still shows the problem.)

Comment: `\inctext` puts its content in a separate page. Why enclose it in a figure?

Comment: Because it should be a float. There is text with some full-page floats.

Comment: Then why `inctext`, why not simply `begin{figure*}[p]`?

Comment: Because of what the incgraph package can do, in particular resizing. This is a very trimmed down MWE that shows the problem, very far away from the real document.